# How to change @html.editor so that it can be entered when I want to add new data and it will be disabled when I want to edit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

How to change `@html.editor` so that it can be entered when I want to add new data?
And `@html.editor` will be inactive when I want to edit? (ASP.NET MVC)

```
@Html.EditorFor(item => data.id, 
                "DataShow" + (isEdit ? "Edit" : "Add"), 
                new { 
                      disabled = "disabled", 
                      type = "text", 
                      name = "id MIDTID", 
                      placeholder = "MIDTID Id"
                })
```

Comment: Just a tip: If the editor should be able to be submitted with form but preventing user input, use `@readonly = "readonly"` instead of `disabled` attribute.

Comment: how to make a condition in the @ html.editor? when you want to add it can be inputted and when edited it can only be seen

Comment: Hi Setia, Put the if condition outside the Html.Helper

 @if (isEdit)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(item => item.Password, "DataShowEdit", new { disabled = "disabled", type = "text", name = "id MIDTID", placeholder = "MIDTID Id" })
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(item =>item.Password, "DataShowAdd", new { type = "text", name = "id MIDTID", placeholder = "MIDTID Id" })

        }